# Adding related Ruby on Rails activeRecord objects to an array in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, enumeration

I am trying to add objects to an array in Ruby on Rails in a :helper_method in the application controller. In this example, other_roommates comes back as an array with 2 objects in it, of type house_tenant, which is exactly what I would expect.

```
  @other_roommates = Array.new

  @other_roommates = current_house.house_tenant.where("active = '1' AND person_id != ?", current_user.id)
```

What I want to do is make an array with the related object Person from each of those HouseTenants, but when I do this I get exactly the same array as above:

```
  @other_roommates = Array.new

  joins = current_house.house_tenant.where("active = '1' AND person_id != ?", current_user.id)

  joins.each do |join|
    @other_roommates << join.person
  end
```

I would expect in the above case that the array would have the 2 Person objects that are related to the house_tenant objects in it. I can get to those Person objects in the view by enumerating through the other_roommate array and calling .person on each object there, but it doesn't make sense that it doesn't work here in the Application Controller. To further confuse me, I tried 2 more tests:

```
  for x in 0..joins.count - 1
    @other_roommates << joins[x]
  end
```

and

```
  for x in 0..joins.count - 1
    @other_roommates << x
  end
```

When I output the contents of the array, both examples give me the exact same thing "0, 1", or the value of x. Here's the loop that's in the view:

```
<% other_roommates.each do |roommate| %>
<%= roommate %>
<% end %>
```

For what it's worth, all this is running on a Heroku Cedar stack. I know this is probably a basic issue, but I have no idea what the heck I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: here's the relationships from the model classes. I can traverse the objects in exactly the same way if I do it in a view instead of in the ApplicationController, just for some reason here it doesn't work.

```
class HouseTenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :person
end


class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_tenant
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :house_tenant
end
```

The schema for house_tenant has 'house_id' and 'person_id', and the relationships work just fine in the console as well.

Comment: Could you post the association definitions?

Comment: The code seems syntactically correct, you might have trouble with your associations. Please share them

Comment: I hope that helps, thanks for checking it out!